Exception caught by widgets library ═RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
i am having this error i tried to use list of cart from api getcartproducts to store in products list then to use in my widgets i don't know what is the issue!
if some one can help me i am not expert i am just student even i am getting Scnakbar sayin fetched items success fully and showing this error
import 'package:softiweer_shop/models/product.dart';
import 'package:softiweer_shop/screens/shop/cart/services/cart_services.dart';

import '../../../details/services/productdetailsservices.dart';

class CartProduct extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  const CartProduct({super.key, required this.index});

  @override
  State<CartProduct> createState() => _CartProductState();
}

class _CartProductState extends State<CartProduct> {
  Productdetailsservices productdetailsservices = Productdetailsservices();
  CartServices cartServices = CartServices();
  bool isLoading = true;
  List products = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    getcartPro();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> getcartPro() async {
    try {
      products = await productdetailsservices.getCartProducts(context: context);
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error fetching cart products: $e");
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  void addCart(String id) async {
    productdetailsservices.addToCart(context: context, productId: id);
  }

  void removeCartItem(String id) async {
    cartServices.removeCartItem(context: context, productId: id);
  }

  void deleteCartItem(int index) async {
    cartServices.deleteCartItem(context: context, index: index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var productCart = products[widget.index];
    var product = Product.fromMap(productCart['product']);
    var quantity = productCart['quantity'] ?? 0;

    return isLoading
        ? Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: size.height * 0.18,
              child: Card(
                surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(flex: 3, child: Image.network(product.image)),
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 7,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            ListTile(
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 6),
                              title: Text(product.name),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                product.description,
                                maxLines: 2,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),
                              trailing: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () => deleteCartItem(widget.index),
                                  icon: const Icon(
                                    Icons.delete,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  )),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () =>
                                          removeCartItem(product.id.toString()),
                                      icon: const Icon(
                                        Icons.remove,
                                        color: Colors.orange,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: 20,
                                      width: 20,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Colors.orange,
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          quantity.toString(),
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    IconButton(
                                      onPressed: () =>
                                          {addCart(product.id.toString())},
                                      icon: const Icon(
                                        Icons.add,
                                        color: Colors.orange,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                                  child: Text('\$${product.price}'),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}


products list is empty while you are trying to access out of range index. ensure it's successfully get initialized.
